# actor handling multiple messages at the same time

Tags: scala, akka

I know one of the advantages of the actor model is that by handling only one message at a time, concurrency issues are simplified. But it seems to me that my actor is handling multiple messages. In pseudo code I have

```
var status = 0
def receive = {
  case DoSomething => 
    val dest = sender()
    status = 0

    for {
      otherActor <- resolveOtherActor("/user/OtherActor")
    } yield {
      for {
      res <- {status = 1
              otherActor ? doSomething1
              }
      res <- {status = 2
              otherActor ? doSomething2
              }
      } yield {
        dest ! status
      }
    }

  case GetStatus => sender() ! status
}
```

If I send a DoSomething messages to this actor, and then immediately send GetStatus to this actor repeatedly, I will see status 0, 1 and 2 coming back in sequence. If the actor model only handled one message at a time, I would only ever see status 2 being returned, since I wouldn't have access to the intermediate status.

It seems that locks are still necessary with the actor pattern. What am I missing?

Comment: Locks are not necessary. The ask pattern creates a Future, at that moment the context change and the GetStatus message can come in, maybe that can be the problem. Try to eliminate the ask operations (?)  and try again.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 that is what i thought might be happening. However, in a system that is using many akka constructs, there tons of 'asks' and other future operations. So it doesnt seem like actors solve the concurrency issue unless they don't operate on futures, which is probably not a realistic scenario.

Comment: I wouldn´t use ask inside the actor in that case. If the receive method has to send other messages i´d use tell (!) instead. In case that you need to know what is happening in the "otherActor", this should send back other message you´d need to handle adding another 'case' clause.  With mutable state use of Futures should be avoided.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 that makes sense. I will try to refactor that way. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All bets are off when you close over an actor's mutable state and expose it to other threads, which is what your code is doing when it mutates `status` inside a (nested) `Future`. The Akka [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/general/jmm.html#actors-and-shared-mutable-state) clearly warns against this.

An actor does process one message at a time:

```
var status = 0
def receive = {
  case IncrementStatus =>
    status += 1
  case GetStatus =>
    val s = status
    sender ! s
}
```

Sending an `IncrementStatus`, another `IncrementStatus`, then a `GetStatus` message from the same sender to the above actor will cause that sender to receive a `2`.

However, trying to do the same thing with `Future`s does not guarantee the same outcome, because a `Future` is completed asynchronously. For example:

```
object NumService {
  // calculates arg + 1 in the future
  def addOne(arg: Int): Future[Int] = {
    Future { arg + 1 } 
  }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  var status = 0
  def receive = {
    case IncrementStatusInFuture =>
      val s = status
      NumService.addOne(s)
                .map(UpdateStatus(_))
                .pipeTo(self)

    case UpdateStatus(num) =>
      status = num

    case GetStatus =>
      val s = status
      sender ! s
  }
}
```

We `map` the `Future` to create a `Future[UpdateStatus]`, then [pipe](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/futures.html#use-with-actors) to the actor itself the result of that `Future`.

If we send an `IncrementStatusInFuture`, another `IncrementStatusInFuture`, then a `GetStatus` message to `MyActor` from the same sender, we cannot guarantee that the sender will receive a `2`. The actor processes those three messages in order, but one or both of the calls to `NumService.addOne` might not have completed by the time the actor processes the `GetStatus` message. This nondeterministic behavior is a characteristic of a `Future`; it is not a violation of the actor principle of one-message-at-a-time processing.